# Can somebody explain this mystery of why these memory pinouts don't match?

Tags: memory, ddr2

I'm looking at a stick of DDR2 RAM side-by-side with another labeled PC2-5300F. The notch on the latter looks like DDR, not DDR2. The workstation it came out of says DDR2 in the specs. Wikipedia says PC2-5300 ought to be DDR2. I'm confused.

[image]

Comment: For reference: [DDR, DDR2, DDR3 \[graphic\]](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3emf2.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one on the bottom is a [fully-buffered DDR2 DIMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_Buffered_DIMM), which has a slightly different fit than normal DIMMs.

Answer (score 1):

The 5300F is DDR2, but with error correction. Such modules are used on servers and very robust machines. Apparently the pinout is not the same as that of conventional DDR2 modules.